# Share icons stored in app package with Fileprovider

Tags: android, xml, android-fileprovider

i'm new to use FileProvider so sorry for (maybe) a noob question. I want to use FileProvider to share some icon stored inside the app package but i have no idea where i should put my icons. I should create a new directory where put my images ? I'm only interested to get the paths of internal app icons to share it. At the moment i did that:

```
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.customizer.smart"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/icon_paths">

        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

res/xml/icon_paths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_icons" path="icons/"/></paths>
```

i tried this workaround to get the path of a drawable png but it doesn't works:

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_action_pip;
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.customizer.smart", new File (imageUri));
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /drawable:/2130837595
```

So where i should put my icons and how i can retrieve their paths ? Thanks.